# Query result size in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is there a way to know the query response size in Snowflake?

For example, in BigQuery we get the size from the temporal table created by BigQuery in a query job.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not use a transient table? Out of interest, why do you want to know this information?

Comment: Yes, transient table will allow us to have data for more time, but the problem is that they are not automatically deleted after a while, right? We need it for a specific use case: the most important requirement for that is the response goes to a browser app and we want to limit the response to something like 100MB per request for example

Comment: OK - but in that case none of the size information in Snowflake is going to help you. The data in Snowflake is heavily compressed (and size information is for that compressed data) - if you send that data to a web app then it would obviously be de-compressed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After you run a query you can always refer back to its cached results. All you need to know is the query id and scan for its results. Then you can determine the size of those results by whatever method you choose to measure the size - for example, the length of json encoding all columns.

In code:

```
-- run a query then get its id

set last_query_id = (select last_query_id());

select sum(length(to_json(object_construct(a.*)))) table_encoded_size
from table(result_scan($last_query_id)) a;
```

Comment: I'm glad it worked @oleurud. Please mark this answer as accepted as a token that it worked for you :)

Comment: Hi Felipe, I had to add an `object_construct` function to the chain to make it work: It would be: `select sum(length(to_json(object_construct(a.*)))) table_encoded_size
from table(result_scan($last_query_id)) a;`

Comment: Thanks for sharing that tip @juanra! The query worked with the data I had, and I'm glad that you found a good solution when it didn't

Comment: I want to share our final results. Using the result_scan solution when we're using a 1.5GB table, we get these results: `SELECT * FROM BIG_TABLE`: 19s (first time) or hit cache. `result_scan query`: 34 seg (returning 1.599.524.104 bytes) Using a temporary table: `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE XX AS (SELECT * FROM BIG_TABLE)`: 29 seg and `SELECT BYTES FROM  WHERE table_name = 'XX'`: 600 ms (2.353.437.184 bytes).

As you see there are some differences in time required and the size results. Depending on your case requirements, it could be better one or the other

Comment: Some of those results are surprising! Happy to go deeper through email if you'd like